# CQ5 Calling Custom Utility Methods in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, adobe, aem

I am currently using CQ5 and trying to call a custom java utility function that I wrote in the bundle section of my cq5 code. I am calling this from a components jsp.

In my common bundle I have a utility class under *src/main/java*. My package is something like *com.test.utility* and my file is *jcrUtility.java*. Inside the java file I have something like:

```
public static ArrayList<String> propertyToArrayList(Node n) { ... }
```

In my component's jsp file I have something like this:

```
<% page import="com.test.utility.jcrUtility"%>
<% 
   Node n = currentNode;
   ArrayList<String> propList = jcrUtility.propertyToArrayList(n);
%>
```

In both my java class and my jsp file I have the correct other libraries imported such as *java.util.ArrayList*, *javax.jcr.Node*, etc. I have also compiled my OSGI bundle and updated it in the Bundles web console.

The current exception I am receiving is as follows:

```
org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
The method propertyToArrayList(Node n) is undefined for the type jcrUtility
```

I am not sure what the problem is considering the java in my utility class and the java in my jsp looks sound. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the following things ?

1. Your Bundle is "**Active**" and "com.test.utility" package is shown in the "**Export Package**" section.
2. Your sample shows you are importing only jcrUtility class in your JSP. `"<% page import="com.test.utility.jcrUtility"%>"` . Can you make sure you are importing `javax.jcr.Node` too ?
3. You should not need to assign currentNode to a variable. You can directly pass currentNode to the jcrUtility.propertyToArrayList method.

   ```
   ArrayList<String> propList = jcrUtility.propertyToArrayList(currentNode);
   ```

Comment: I checked and my bundle is "**Active**" and my package is in the "**Export Package**".

As far as importing things I have javax.jcr.Node imported. And yes I know that I can just pass currentNode as a variable. Any suggestions?